DocuSign - PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified
DocuSign is working fine, but suddenly I received the error: PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, with the message: 'The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.' How can I resolve this issue?
I have already searched the internet, but I can't find anything. Can anyone help me

"An Integrator key was not specified" indicates that your request was missing the Authorisation header needed to authenticate your request. I'd recommend checking if your application is setting the authorization header after obtaining the access token
